# Why is the "CREATE DATABASE" command not working?

Tags: postgresql

[image: POSTGRES command not working in sqlshell]

When I try to use SQLSHELL "CREATE DATABASE test". I don't get a prompt that anything was created (not sure if i'm supposed to). Then when I check to see if it was created ("\l"). Nothing is there.
What is happening?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you terminate the command with `;`?

Comment: @akop I feel like an idiot. Thank-you! This worked

Comment: @KenWhite I appreciate it. My apologies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to terminate SQL commands with `;`.

In your case:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE test;
```

Comment: Since I don't need the `;` in JavaScript anymore I tend to forget that other languages actually need it. Thanks for the reminder... 1h of trying everything and it was the stupid `;` that was missing...